# Strategy for scraping web pages, maximizing information gathered

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, classification

Here's the problem:

Users register for a site and can pick one of 8 job categories, or choose to skip this step. I want to classify the users who've skipped that step into job categories, based on the domain name in their email address.

Current setup:

Using a combination of Beautiful Soup and nltk, I scrape the homepage and look for links to pages on the site that contain the word "about". I scrape that page, too. I've copied the bit of code that does the scraping at the end of this post.

The issue:

I'm not getting enough data to get a good learning routine in place. I'd like to know if my scraping algorithm is set up for success--in other words, are there any gaping holes in my logic, or any better way to ensure that I have a good chunk of text that describes what kind of work a company does?

The (relevant) code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import httplib2 as http
import nltk


# Only these characters are valid in a url
ALLOWED_CHARS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-._~:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="


class WebPage(object):
    def __init__(self, domain):
        """
            Constructor

            :param domain: URL to look at
            :type domain: str
        """
        self.url = 'http://www.' + domain

        try:
            self._get_homepage()
        except: # Catch specific here?
            self.homepage = None

        try:
            self._get_about_us()
        except:
            self.about_us = None

    def _get_homepage(self):
        """
            Open the home page, looking for redirects
        """
        import re

        web = http.Http()
        response, pg = web.request(self.url)

        # Check for redirects:
        if int(response.get('content-length',251)) < 250:
            new_url = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', pg)[0]
            if len(new_url): # otherwise there's not much I can do...
                self.url = ''.join(x for x in new_url if x in ALLOWED_CHARS)
                response, pg = web.request(self.url)

        self.homepage = self._parse_html(nltk.clean_html(pg))
        self._raw_homepage = pg

    def _get_about_us(self):
        """
            Soup-ify the home page, find the "About us" page, and store its contents in a
            string
        """
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(self._raw_homepage)
        links = [x for x in soup.findAll('a') if x.get('href', None) is not None]
        about = [x.get('href') for x in links if 'about' in x.get('href', '').lower()]

        # need to find about or about-us
        about_us_page = None
        for a in about:
            bits = a.strip('/').split('/')
            if len(bits) == 1:
                about_us_page = bits[0]
            elif 'about' in bits[-1].lower():
                about_us_page = bits[-1]

        # otherwise assume shortest string is top-level about pg.
        if about_us_page is None and len(about):
            about_us_page = min(about, key=len)

        self.about_us = None
        if about_us_page is not None:
            self.about_us_url = self.url + '/' + about_us_page
            web = http.Http()
            response, pg = web.request(self.about_us_url)
            if int(response.get('content-length', 251)) > 250:
                self.about_us = self._parse_html(nltk.clean_html(pg))

    def _parse_html(self, raw_text):
        """
            Clean html coming from a web page. Gets rid of
                - all '\n' and '\r' characters
                - all zero length words
                - all unicode characters that aren't ascii (i.e., &...)
        """
        lines = [x.strip() for x in raw_text.splitlines()]
        all_text = ' '.join([x for x in lines if len(x)]) # zero length strings
        return [x for x in all_text.split(' ') if len(x) and x[0] != '&']
```

Comment: Since you've tagged this [tag:beautifulsoup], It would be useful if you mention the url or give a snippet of the webpage that you want to parse. And it is hard to understand the exact problem from the code you have provided (which is for connecting to the webpage).

Comment: I have a string of about 6000 urls here, so I'm not sure a list would be informative. I want to know if there are ways to improve the scraping/parsing algorithm above to work in the most general fashion as possible. Of course, any general tips would be greatly appreciated, too.

Comment: Adding one example would be good enough to give some context.  1 >>> 0

Comment: @AaronD The point is that I want to do this generally, for any domain I'm given. If I put up an example of one domain that I'm trying to scrape, I'll get a dozen answers telling me how to scrape that domain. But that's not good enough, because I'd have to change my algorithm for each new domain I get. Does that make sense? Said another way, I have no a priori knowledge of who is going to register for my site, so I have to assume complete generality.

Comment: On a side note, I would separate the scraping and processing into two steps.  First, go download the info and store the raw result in a file or database. Then you can reparse your results a number of times until you get a good result, without hammering the websites of the companies you are looking at.

Answer (score 1):

It is outside of what you are asking, but I would look at calling an external data source that has already collected this information.  A good place to find such a service would be on the [Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/) (for instance [Mergent Company  Fundamentals](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/mergent-company-fundamentals)).  Not all the data on Programmable Web is up-to-date but it seems like a lot of API providers are out there.

Comment: Very nice. I hadn't heard of Programmable Web before.